# Shorten URL for htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am editing a code for making my url short but there is a problem with it had to have two variable so that it can be found in server? The code i create is like this:

```
RewriteRule product/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ product_info.php?ItemName=$1&uid=$2
```

result:

```
http://Example.com.my/product/NBR/901003-7
```

if the uid is being taken out the url will become error and show that file could not be found. is it about the htaccess code or the php code that cause this problem.

the url that i hope to get is this:
http://Example.com.my/product/NBR

Comment: Your pattern will only match URL's with two segments after the `product/`, so if you call `product/foo`, the pattern won't match and it will try and find a folder called `product/foo` on the server. I would recommend that you look into using a router instead of adding a bunch of rewrite rules. It will make your code way more portable between different web servers (and, depending on the router implementation) much more readable and easier to manage.

Comment: You do not allow to omit last element, only last slash. Create another rule before this one without uid part

Comment: Thank for the reply, but i am new in this htaccess code.. Is there any example so that i can follow on editing my code..

Answer (score 0):

You can set up 2 different Rewrite rule in the .htacess file

1. Rewrite rule if you have uid in your URL

   **RewriteRule product/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ product_info.php?ItemName=$1&uid=$2**
2. Rewrite rule if you do not have uid in your URL

   **RewriteRule product/([^/])$ product_info.php?ItemName=$1**

***Here is the screenshot:***

**With UID**

[image]

**Without UID**

[image]

**.htacess code**

[image]

Hope it works for you.

Comment: thank for the reply but as my mention above the problem is when i take out the uid and the result will be document not found in the server.

Comment: I understood your problem. You are trying to satisfy the 2 different case with the same htaccess rewrite rule. If you write 2 separate rule one for with uid or other for without uid. Your both cases will work.

Comment: i tried to have both rule together but the result is the same at the one without uid. the result is show as the document not found in the server. 404 not found.  is there other solution?

Comment: You may be putting with uid rule first. Move without uid rule first then with rule id second

Comment: AddType application/x-httpd-php .xml
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule index_(.*)_(.*)\.htm$ index.php?id=$1&lang=$2
#RewriteRule products_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)\.htm$ products.php?cat=$1&brand=$2&pf=$3
#RewriteRule product_info_(.*)\.htm$ product_info.php?uid=$1


#RewriteRule product/([^/.]+)/?$ product_info.php?ItemName=$1
#RewriteRule product/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ product_info.php?ItemName=$1&uid=$2
RewriteRule product/([^/])/([^/])$ product_info.php?ItemName=$1&uid=$2
RewriteRule product/([^/])$ product_info.php?ItemName=$1

Comment: I try and is the same..  the one with uid is work but without is still 404 not found is it possible to fix it with code like Query string ?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: for computer? windows 10.

Comment: what do you think that is causing this trouble? is it os problem? or is just some code problem? i am really new for this htaccess code i really had no idea on this thing..

Comment: I think the solution is correct. You just need to work out on htaccess rule syntax. As different OS apache has its own way. I faced similar kind of issue before.